Is it possible to use slog.LogValue for a structure field?
type Password string

func (u Password) LogValue() slog.Value {
    return slog.StringValue("*****")
}

func TestPassword(t *testing.T) {
    logger := slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil))
    slog.SetDefault(logger)

    var pass Password = "1234"

    logger.Warn("", "pass:", pass) // pass:=*****

    u := struct {
        Name     string
        Password Password
    }{
        Name:     "1",
        Password: pass,
    }

    logger.Warn("", "user:", u) // user:="{Name:1 Password:1234}"
}

As you can see from the example, LogValue does not work when the type is a structure field. Is it possible to somehow make LogValue also used to transform fields without implementing it for the structure itself?

Try using a simple fmt.Stringer

You can't, since slog only considers the arguments types and leaves formatting the value to the fmt package.
So either you implement the slog.LogValuer on the top level type or you use something the fmt package knows, like JimB's suggestion  fmt.Stringer (Go Playground):
type Password string

func (u Password) String() string {
    return "xxxxx"
}

func main() {
    logger := slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil))
    slog.SetDefault(logger)

    var pass Password = "1234"

    u := struct {
        Name     string
        Password Password
    }{
        Name:     "1",
        Password: pass,
    }

    logger.Warn("", "user:", u) // user:="{Name:1 Password:xxxxx}"
}

